# MonoTouch Binding Handler

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

Hi i'm trying to do do some binding for the IDBlue framework on Monotouch there is one thing that i don't understand how it should translated is this:

```
- (SendStatus *) getTagInfo:(RfidTag*) tag withHandler: (id&lt;IHfResponseHandler&gt;)  handler
```

How i should map id on mono touch?
I looked on mono touch docs but i din't find a similar issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is as simple as this.

```
[Export ("getTagInfo:withHandler:")]
public SendStatus GetTagInfoWithHandler (RfidTag tag, IHfResponseHandler handler);
```

Or you may be able to try a weak handler version.

```
[Export ("getTagInfo:withHandler:")]
public SendStatus GetTagInfoWithWeakHandler (RfidTag tag, NSObject handler);
```